# How to generate large XML file with "for" construction in Python without predefined structure?

Tags: python, xml, xml-generation

I have 4000+ key-values records in REDIS.
My XML file to server should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="Address">Address</string>
     <string name="AppName">App</string>
</resources>
```

I need to generate XML file with all values I can get from DB (the number may be different).
All examples I saw before were with pre-defined structure - it is always known in advance how many rows there will be. But in my case it is always different number. How to generate XML file "with cycle"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jinja2 :

```
 from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape   
 import os

 def write_xml(list_data):
      env = Environment(
               loader = PackageLoader('path', 'to', 'template', 'directory'),
               autoescape = select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
               )
      template = env.get_template('template.xml')
      output_from_parsed_template = template.render(values=list_data)
      path = os.path.join("path", "to", "output")
      with open(str(path), "wb+") as fh:
            fh.write(output_from_parsed_template.encode('utf-8'))
```

Your template.xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
       {% for value in values %}
         <string name="Address">{{ value.Address }}</string>
         <string name="AppName">{{ value.App }}</string>
       {% endfor %}
     </resources>
```